# $f_{\mathcal{B}}$ is continuous iff $\mathcal{B}$ is a clopen cover of $X.$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, category-theory, compactness

**DEFINITION.**

If $\mathcal{B}$ is a disjoint cover of $X,$ then we can define a function $$f_{\mathcal{B}}: X \rightarrow \mathcal{B},$$given by the formula $$f_{\mathcal{B}}(x) = \textbf{the unique $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B$}.$$And to get some topology involved, we give $\mathcal{B}$ the discrete topology.

**The problem is:**

Let $X$ be a space and let $\mathcal{B}$ be a disjoint cover of $X.$

$(a)$ Show that  $f_{\mathcal{B}}$ is continuous iff $\mathcal{B}$ is a clopen cover of $X.$

**My question is:**

If I know this definition:

**Definition:**

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are two covers of $X.$ We say that $\mathcal{B}$ refines $\mathcal{A}$ if each member of  $\mathcal{B}$ is contained in some member of $\mathcal{A}.$ We say that $\mathcal{B}$ strictly refines $\mathcal{A}$ if each member of $\mathcal{B}$ is a proper subset of some member of $\mathcal{A}.$ if $\mathcal{B}$ strictly refines $\mathcal{A},$ we write $\mathcal{A} < \mathcal{B}.$

And if I know the proof of this problem:

Let $X$ be a compact metric space that is totally disconnected, and let $\epsilon > 0.$

(a) Show that $X$ has a finite cover $\mathcal{A}$ clopen sets with diameter at most $\epsilon.$

(b) Show that there is a clopen cover $\mathcal{B}$  such that $\mathcal{B}$ refines $\mathcal{A}$ and distinct numbers of $\mathcal{B}$ are disjoint.

How can I proof the required above?

**EDIT:**
As my question above was answered by Brian in the comments, My new question is: Could anyone please provide me with some details about the idea of the proof either forward or backward direction ?

Comment: The definition that you quote and the result about compact, totally disconnected metric spaces are irrelevant; you prove the result by showing directly from the definition that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Ok that is a very good hint @BrianM.Scott

Comment: Could you please provide me with some details about the idea of the proof? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: I really can’t anything more without simply doing the proof myself. What are the open sets in $\mathscr{B}$? If $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{B}$, what can you say about the set $\bigcup\mathscr{A}$ in the space $X$? Use what you know about the members of $\mathscr{B}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function into a discrete space $D$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}[\{d\}]$ is open for all $d$, as singletons form a base for $D$.

Now, $f_{\mathcal{B}}^{-1}[\{B\}] = B$ by definition.  So all $B$ are clopen, as all singletons in a discrete space are.

Comment: it is not clear for me why $\mathcal{B} $ is a discrete space of singletons. Could you please explain this more?

Comment: If $X$ is a set in the discrete topology, the set \{\{x\}\mid x \in X\}$ is a base for the topology, as all sets are unions of singletons.

Comment: Could you please look at this question if you have time ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3618739/proving-existence-of-sequence-of-finite-clopen-and-disjoint-cover-each-member-w