# Proving existence of sequence of finite, clopen and disjoint cover each member with diameter at most $1/n.$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, compactness

I want to answer the following question:

Let $X$ be a totally disconnected, compact, and perfect metric space.

(a) Show that there is a sequence of covers $\mathcal{A}_{1}, \mathcal{A}_{2}, ... $ such that:

1- Each $\mathcal{A}$ is a finite disjoint clopen cover,

2- Each member of $\mathcal{A}_{n}$ has diameter at most $\frac{1}{n},$ and

3- $\mathcal{A}_{1} < \mathcal{A}_{2} < ... < \mathcal{A}_{n} < \mathcal{A}_{n + 1} < ...\, .$

Could anyone help me in proving so please?

Comment: This just applying (b) of your previous question in a recursion. Nothing more.

Comment: The strict refinement relations should be the other way around of course, certainly in light of the diameter restrictions. So $\mathcal{A}_{n+1} \prec \mathcal{A}_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: In the end you’ll get that $X$ is the limit of an inverse sequence of finite discrete spaces; I think that’s the end goal of this series of exercises?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I am still unable to prove $(b)$ of my previous question.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Is your second comment saying that there is a typo? .... I do not think so as our definition for strict refinement is reversed.

Comment: I guess you define $\mathcal{A} < \mathcal{B}$ as "$\mathcal{A}$ is (strictly) refined by $\mathcal{B}$" not $\mathcal{A} \prec \mathcal{B}$, which means $\mathcal{A}$ refines $\mathcal{B}$" usually.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes exactly.

Comment: You nowhere wrote this definition, while you did write the definition for refinement earlier, hence the confusion on my part. And $<$ and $\prec$ are pretty similar too.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I thought that you remember this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3619577/what-can-you-say-about-the-map-phi-if-mathcala-mathcalb-i-e-math?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the proposition $(b)$ in [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3618562/4280), we have $\mathcal{A}_1$ of sets of diameter $< 1$.

If we have constructed $\mathcal{A}_i, i \le n$ already, obeying the demands, we just pick by the same problem, a disjoint clopen finite cover $\mathcal{A}_{n+1} \prec \mathcal{A}_n$ such that all its sets have diameter $< \frac{1}{n+1}$ and this preserves all properties ( when we modify the refinement relation as I said)

So the sequence exists by the recursion theorem.

Comment: But I do not know recursion theorem.

Comment: Which statement of recursion theorem are you speaking about?

Comment: @Happy something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem); standard set theory. It allows us to define a sequence of sets by recursion, and get a well-defined (in axiomatic sense) sequence. This is mostly used (without mentioning it) in text books; most people will find it to obvious to state. It's closely related to proofs by induction.

Comment: why not by induction and not recursion?

Comment: It is not clear for me how you adjusted the argument of the diameter to be less than $1/n$ are you using Archemidian propwety?

Comment: @Happy no, I didn't adjust an argument, nor do I use the Archimedean property here. The diameter property is automatic because in the very beginning we refine small enough balls.

Comment: why diameter $1/(n+1)$ and not $1/n$? could you please explain this point more?

Comment: @Happy we’re constructing $\mathcal{A}_{n+1}$ and that diameter has to be strictly smaller than $\\frac{1}{n+1}$. Every family has diameter less than 1 over its index.